# Not able to fetch promotions from fredhopper

Tags: dd4t, smarttarget

I am not able to fetch promotions created through Targetting tab from Tridion 2013 SP1.I can see below logs in my application which is showing no error in fetching the promotions. Find below thion.e logs generated in smarttarget specific log of the application:

> 2015-04-17 16:09:13,903 DEBUG SessionProcessor - parsing
>   'authorization' request header 2015-04-17 16:09:13,903 DEBUG
>   SessionProcessor - parsing 'authorization' request header 2015-04-17
>   16:09:14,153 DEBUG QueryTagHandler - Starting query with a timeout of
>   200 ms 2015-04-17 16:09:14,154 DEBUG QueryTagHandler - Adding
>   Publication Scope trigger for tcm:0-1033-1 2015-04-17 16:09:14,155
>   DEBUG QueryTagHandler - Added Region Scope trigger for Header
>   2015-04-17 16:09:14,155 DEBUG QueryTagHandler - Adding ambient data
>   2015-04-17 16:09:14,155 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper - reading defined
>   trigger types from claim store 2015-04-17 16:09:14,182 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataHelper - for uri path:
>   'taf_claim_ambientdata_sessioncartridge_useragent', defined prefix:
>   'sc_ua'  is found 2015-04-17 16:09:14,183 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper -
>   returning trigger url-param name: sc_ua_browser 2015-04-17
>   16:09:14,184 DEBUG TriggerTypesHelper - trigger url-param:
>   'sc_ua_browser' is found as defined in FH 2015-04-17 16:09:14,186
>   DEBUG AmbientDataHelper - for uri path:
>   'taf_claim_ambientdata_sessioncartridge_useragent', defined prefix:
>   'sc_ua'  is found 2015-04-17 16:09:14,186 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper -
>   returning trigger url-param name: sc_ua_os 2015-04-17 16:09:14,187
>   DEBUG TriggerTypesHelper - trigger url-param: 'sc_ua_os' is found as
>   defined in FH 2015-04-17 16:09:14,188 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper -
>   returning trigger url-param name:
>   taf_claim_ambientdata_definedtriggertypes 2015-04-17 16:09:14,190
>   DEBUG AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger url-param name:
>   taf_request_full_url 2015-04-17 16:09:14,194 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper -
>   for uri path: 'taf_claim_ambientdata_sessioncartridge_useragent',
>   defined prefix: 'sc_ua'  is found 2015-04-17 16:09:14,194 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger url-param name: sc_ua_isbot
>   2015-04-17 16:09:14,194 DEBUG TriggerTypesHelper - trigger url-param:
>   'sc_ua_isbot' is found as defined in FH 2015-04-17 16:09:14,196 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataHelper - for uri path:
>   'taf_claim_ambientdata_sessioncartridge_authorization', defined
>   prefix: 'sc_auth'  is found 2015-04-17 16:09:14,196 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger url-param name:
>   sc_auth_isauthenticated 2015-04-17 16:09:14,197 DEBUG
>   TriggerTypesHelper - trigger url-param: 'sc_auth_isauthenticated' is
>   found as defined in FH 2015-04-17 16:09:14,198 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper
>   - for uri path: 'taf_claim_ambientdata_sessioncartridge_session', defined prefix: 'sc_session'  is found 2015-04-17 16:09:14,199 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger url-param name:
>   sc_session_lifetime 2015-04-17 16:09:14,199 DEBUG TriggerTypesHelper -
>   trigger url-param: 'sc_session_lifetime' is found as defined in FH
>   2015-04-17 16:09:14,201 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger
>   url-param name: taf_response_cookie_generation 2015-04-17 16:09:14,202
>   DEBUG AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger url-param name:
>   taf_tracking_id 2015-04-17 16:09:14,205 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper - for
>   uri path: 'taf_claim_ambientdata_sessioncartridge_session', defined
>   prefix: 'sc_session'  is found 2015-04-17 16:09:14,205 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger url-param name:
>   sc_session_creationtimestamp 2015-04-17 16:09:14,207 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataHelper - for uri path:
>   'taf_claim_ambientdata_sessioncartridge_session', defined prefix:
>   'sc_session'  is found 2015-04-17 16:09:14,207 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper
>   - returning trigger url-param name: sc_session_sessionid 2015-04-17 16:09:14,209 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger url-param
>   name: taf_request_cookies 2015-04-17 16:09:14,211 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger url-param name:
>   taf_claim_ambientdata_footprintcartridge_mobiledevice 2015-04-17
>   16:09:14,213 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger url-param
>   name: taf_claim_ambientdata_footprintcartridge_acceptlanguage
>   2015-04-17 16:09:14,215 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper - for uri path:
>   'taf_claim_ambientdata_sessioncartridge_useragent_browser', defined
>   prefix: 'sc_ua_browser'  is found 2015-04-17 16:09:14,216 DEBUG
>   AmbientDataHelper - returning trigger url-param name:
>   sc_ua_browser_version 2015-04-17 16:09:14,218 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper
>   - returning trigger url-param name: taf_claim_ambientdata_footprintcartridge_devicetype 2015-04-17
>   16:09:14,220 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper - for uri path:
>   'taf_claim_ambientdata_sessioncartridge_useragent_os', defined prefix:
>   'sc_ua_os'  is found 2015-04-17 16:09:14,221 DEBUG AmbientDataHelper -
>   returning trigger url-param name: sc_ua_os_version 2015-04-17
>   16:09:14,222 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Retrieving fredhopper query
>   result from query thread, timeout: 200 ms. 2015-04-17 16:09:14,223
>   DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Started fredhopper query call 2015-04-17
>   16:09:14,224 DEBUG Query - initializing web service client for:
>   http://localhost:8180/fredhopper-ws/services/FASWebService?wsdl
>   2015-04-17 16:09:14,224 DEBUG Query - Constructing Fredhopper query
>   2015-04-17 16:09:14,226 INFO  Query - Executing query:
>   fh_location=//catalog01/en_US/categories<{catalog01_tcm_0_1033_1}&fh_user_date=20150417&st_region=Header&st_active_period=20150417&st_publication=tcm%3A0-1033-1&sc_ua_os=Windows&sc_ua_browser=MSIE&sc_auth_isauthenticated=false&sc_session_lifetime=15&sc_ua_isbot=false
>   2015-04-17 16:09:14,319 DEBUG Query - Query returned 0 item(s)
>   2015-04-17 16:09:14,320 DEBUG Query - Query returned 0 promotion(s):
>   2015-04-17 16:09:14,323 DEBUG TimeoutQueryRunner - Query result
>   retrieved from fredhopper in: 100 ms. 2015-04-17 16:09:14,324 DEBUG
>   ResultSet - ItemsTotalCount = 0. 2015-04-17 16:09:14,328 DEBUG
>   ItemTemplateTagHandler - preparing to loop over 0 objects 2015-04-17
>   16:09:14,329 DEBUG QueryTagHandler - The query tag handling took: 175
>   ms. to render

Can anyone suggest me what I need to verify to get the root cause of the issue. Promotion which I have created is based on browser type(Value as chrome).

Comment: You stated that the trigger is on browser = Chrome, but in the query the browser is Internet Explorer (MSIE). Are you actually viewing the site in Chrome? If so, did you perhaps play around with footprints before and the value is still set?

Comment: Hi Peter, Actually the log I have attached above was just to show that I can see query in log. I had checked with chrome too, but I was unable to find the result. Actually, I have simply created the promotions to show on chrome browser and wanted to show in the page.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a log of a time when you actually experience the problem? It's very helpful in troubleshooting the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Looks lik your promotional content is not published to fredhopper. Can you check your promotional content is going to fredhopper or not..

Comment: Hi Harish,
I have configured fredhopper to show promotions created through Targeting tab of Tridion. Now, I can see my promotion in fredhopper. Unfortunately I am still not able to see my promotion directly in business manager(count is showing but promotions are hidden) but I can see it by hitting url from fredhopper preview. As I can see query executed in log file, Can you suggest if I can run the query directly in fredhopper?

Comment: By Default Promotion  are hidden in fredhopper UI. If you want to change this feature make below changes in you FredHopper.

Go to your Index Server FREDHOPPER_HOME\data\instances\indexer\config directory.
In the config directory, create a file called smarttarget_api_extension.properties.
Open smarttarget_api_extension.properties in a text editor and add:

visible=true

Restart the Query Server.
To hide the Promotions, set visible=false or delete the entire file.